# Unable to Deserialize JSON in an UWP app

Tags: c#, json, parsing, uwp

Hi all I'm trying to parse a JSON into c# classes using Newtonsoft Json. The JSON I'm trying to parse is as follows-

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "bakerloo",
    "name": "Bakerloo",
    "modeName": "tube",
    "disruptions": [ ],
    "created": "2016-05-10T15:41:47.997",
    "modified": "2016-05-10T15:41:47.997",
    "lineStatuses": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "id": 0,
        "statusSeverity": 10,
        "statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "validityPeriods": [ ]
      }
    ],
    "routeSections": [ ],
    "serviceTypes": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Regular",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=Bakerloo&serviceTypes=Regular"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "central",
    "name": "Central",
    "modeName": "tube",
    "disruptions": [ ],
    "created": "2016-05-10T15:41:48.45",
    "modified": "2016-05-10T15:41:48.45",
    "lineStatuses": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "id": 0,
        "statusSeverity": 10,
        "statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "validityPeriods": [ ]
      }
    ],
    "routeSections": [ ],
    "serviceTypes": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Regular",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=Central&serviceTypes=Regular"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The JSON is retrieved via this following code block-

```
public static async Task<List<TubeAPI>> GetTubeStatusAsync()
{
 string url = 
String.Format("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/central,victoria/Status/detail=true&app_id=&app_key=");
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
            var jsonMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TubeAPI>>(jsonMessage);
 return result;
}
```

The classes I'm trying to de serialize into are as follows-

```
public class TubeAPI
    {
        public RootArray[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootArray
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string modeName { get; set; }
        public object[] disruptions { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public DateTime modified { get; set; }
        public Linestatus[] lineStatuses { get; set; }
        public object[] routeSections { get; set; }
        public Servicetype[] serviceTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Linestatus
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int statusSeverity { get; set; }
        public string statusSeverityDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public object[] validityPeriods { get; set; }
    }

    public class Servicetype
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }
```

I've set the debugger at `var result` to debug and see if the parsing goes through and I have data in the classes. But the classes are not populated!. 
[image]

As you can see the `Property1` field is null. I'm confused, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @mason worked! post it as answer please. Also why it's working now? I thought we have to refer to the Rootobject class (as in top most field and in my case it appears to be `Property1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're desserializing as a `List<TubeAPI>`. You should instead be deserializing as a `List<RootArray>`, because that's the structure that corresponds to your JSON. You've got an array of `RootArray`, not an array of `TubeAPI`. If you wrap all the JSON in quotes then you'd have a singular `TubeAPI`.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootArray>>(jsonMessage);
```